# Route to 403 page in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, browser, url-routing, http-status-code-403

I want to browser to show 403 (forbidden page) inside if() loop below in JavaScript (ie: replace window.location = 'unauth.html' statement.). I dont want to reroute to unauth.html page. How can I do that?

```
    $(document).ajaxComplete(function (event, xhr, settings) {
        if (xhr.responseText.indexOf('Unauthorized access') >= 0)
            // Show unauthorized page
            window.location = 'unauth.html';
    });
```

Comment: Thats not a loop, thats a callback. Did it work? Was there an error? What kind of error?

Comment: Tim, I do not want to use unauth.html and want to replace that statement (window.location = 'unauth.html';) to something that shows 403 forbidden page instead. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use that callback function to replace the contents of your page. But I believe you cannot send a http 403 status code via ajax.

In order to clarify, you can get a HTTP status code via ajax but you will not be able to inject that status code to current page without redirecting it.